# Correct vertex shader code? OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, translate-animation, skew

**Edit** Code added, please see below

**Edit 2** - Screenshots from device included at bottom along with explanation

**Edit 3** - New code added

I have 2 classes, a rendered and a custom 'quad' class.

I have these declared at class level in my renderer class:

```
final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
final float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
```

And in my onSurfaceChanged method I have:

@Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

```
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

}
```

and....

```
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(curView.getResources(), R.drawable.box);

        //Create new Dot objects

        dot1 = new Quad();
        dot1.setTexture(curView, myBitmap);
        dot1.setSize(300,187);    //These numbers are the size but are redundant/not used at the moment.

        myBitmap.recycle();


           //Set colour to black
           GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

}
```

And finally from this class, onDrawFrame:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Paint the screen the colour defined in onSurfaceCreated
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     // Set the camera position (View matrix) so looking from the front
   Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Combine
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    dot1.rotateQuad(0,0,45, mMVPMatrix); //x,y,angle and matrix passed in

}
```

Then, in my quad class:

This declared at class level:

```
        private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];        
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mRotationHandle;
//Create our vertex shader
    String strVShader =  
              "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
              "uniform mat4 uRotate;" +
              "attribute vec4 a_position;\n"+
              "attribute vec2 a_texCoords;" +
              "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
              "void main()\n" +
              "{\n" +
         //     "gl_Position = a_position * uRotate;\n"+
         //          "gl_Position = uRotate * a_position;\n"+
               "gl_Position = a_position * uMVPMatrix;\n"+  
        //        "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_position;\n"+  
                  "v_texCoords = a_texCoords;" +
              "}";

    //Fragment shader

    String strFShader =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;" +
        "void main()" +
        "{" +
        "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords);" +
        "}";
```

Then method for setting texture (don't think this is relevant to this problem though!!)

```
    public void setTexture(GLSurfaceView view, Bitmap imgTexture){
        this.imgTexture=imgTexture;

        iProgId = Utils.LoadProgram(strVShader, strFShader);
        iBaseMap = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "u_baseMap");
                iPosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_position");
        iTexCoords = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_texCoords");
        texID = Utils.LoadTexture(view, imgTexture);

    }
```

And finally, my 'rotateQuad' method (which currently is supposed to draw and rotate the quad).

```
public void rotateQuad(float x, float y, int angle, float[] mvpMatrix){

Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 0.1f);

//  Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0);  //Removed temporarily

// Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0);

float[] vertices = {

        -.5f,.5f,0, 0,0,
        .5f,.5f,0, 1,0,
        -.5f,-.5f,0, 0,1,
        .5f,-.5f,0, 1,1

        };

 vertexBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
 vertexBuf.put(vertices).position(0);

//Bind the correct texture
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);      
//Use program
GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
// get handle to shape's transformation matrix
mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");
   // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    // get handle to shape's rotation matrix
mRotationHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uRotate");
  // Apply the projection and view transformation
  GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mRotationHandle, 1, false, mRotationMatrix, 0);

//Set starting position for vertices
vertexBuf.position(0);
//Specify attributes for vertex
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
//Enable attribute for position
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);
//Set starting position for texture
vertexBuf.position(3);
//Specify attributes for vertex
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
//Enable attribute for texture
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);
//Draw it
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

for Edit 2.

This is my quad as drawn in the center of the screen.  No rotation.

[image]

This is the same quad rotated at +45 Degrees with the code "gl_Position = a_position * uMVPMatrix;" + in my vertex shader (it's from a different project now so the shader variable is a_position and not vPosition), it's looks correct!

[image]

However, this is the same quad rotated at +45 Degrees with the 2 shader variables switched (so they read "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_position;" - as you can see, it's not quite right.

Also just a side note, you can't see it here as the quare is symetrical, but each method  also rotates in the opposite direction to the other....

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's really impossible to tell because we don't know what you are passing to these two variables.

OpenGL is column-major format, so if `vPosition` is in fact a vector, and `uMVPMatrix` is a matrix, then the first option is correct, if this is in your shader.

If this is not in your shader but in your program code, then there is not enough information.

If you are using the first option but getting unexpected results, you are likely not computing your matrix properly or not passing the correct vertices.

Comment: Hi @SebbyJohanns, I've edit my Q with more code -is this enough to tell when is happening?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in the vertex shader you should multiple the positions by the MVP, that is

gl_Position = uMVPMatrix *vPosition;

When you change the order this should work...

Comment: Would you have any idea then I when I do things this way, when I rotate, my quad 'distorts' / 'skews' ?

Comment: When you do things which way?  When and how do you apply the rotation transformation?

Comment: Maybe can you upload a picture of the distortion?  It's usually just a matter of applying a model transformation in the wrong order...

Comment: Sure @paulczak, I've edited my question with screenshots - any idea why this is happening?  thanks!!

Comment: Thanks so much for these suggestions @paulczak, unfortunately when I apply the line above, I just get blank screen (I've also swapped the other line around as suggested) :-(

Comment: With only rotation and not translation?  Black screen (as in the clear color is what is shown?)

Comment: Yeah, with "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_position;\n"+  in the vertex shader and with my translation line temporarily removed.  I just get the clear colour displayed.  If I change multiplication line back, to as it was originally, I get the quad show up? I will edit my code back to what I had originally so you can see how I've constructed my class if it helps......

Comment: And with the line multiplying Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0); changed to Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix,0, mProjMatrix, 0);?

Comment: Yeah, it comes out just with the clear colour.  Wierd!  I've posted pretty all the relevant code.  I really hope you can spot what is wrong and I really do appreciate your efforts here @paulczak (I've put everything in the code back to 'default' for now) so as it stands, the code draws a rotating quad (clockwise) bang in the center of the screen, no distortion......thanks again.

Comment: in rotate quad - the line GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf); should probably be GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 12);  as the packing is bytes 0-11 are verts.  
In the onSurfaceCreated() method you make a bitmap, send a ref to a Quad type and then recycle() the bitmap.  Unless Quad does a deep copy within it, the bitmap will be lose the moment recycle is called.  I'm pretty sure this may not be what you want.  While the texture coordinate bug may have led to a blank screen... it seems too minor

Comment: Eclipse just throws up an error if I put 12 there, I don't think it's expecting an int there :-(

Comment: also Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 0.1f); should be Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1f);.  Calling  vertexBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
 every iteration will likely cause you to run out of memory and force unnecessary GC calls (especially since the intrinsic vertices are fixed).  Additionally, the locations of the uniforms don't change iteration to iteration so finding them and storing them during initial surface creation is sufficient.

Comment: Well, eclipse probably thought you were still trying to use the identical call to the method that takes a buffer as the final argument as opposed to the one that uses a buffer object.  In your case I'd split the texture coordinates from the vertex coordinates into 2 arrays and send each in separately.  The other option is to make a vertex buffer object, bind that buffer and use offsets into that buffer.  I had thought that you were making a buffer object (which you are not) which is why I had made that suggestion to change the part to an int.

Comment: @paulczak you wrote "Normally you'll see a lot of books assume the matrices get multiplied like this: Model*View*projection*vert" -- but this is surely completely wrong. You either multiply vert*modelView*projection OR you multiple projection*modelView*vert. The order you've suggested is not correct at all. In a column-major format, such as a GL Shader, you'd use projection*modelView*vert. Now these `Matrix` functions are not part of OpenGL, they are a math library you are using, maybe Android-specific? So I don't know if they are column-major or row-major or how they work.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns, Android specifies them in column-major mode also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the help.

I managed to track down the problem (For the most part).  I will show what I did.

It was the following line:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

As you can see I was multiplying the matrices and storing them back into one that I was using in the multiplication.

So I created a new matrix called mvpMatrix2 and stored the results in that.  Then passed that to my vertex shader.

```
//Multiply matrices
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix2, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

//get handle to shape's transformation matrix
mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");

//Give to vertex shader variable
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix2, 0);
```

After applying this, there is no distortion (And also, with regards to my other question here [Using Matrix. Rotate in OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837177/using-matrix-translate-in-opengl-es-2-0) I am able to translate the centre of the quad). I say 'for the most part' because however, when I rotate it, it rotates backwards (so if I say rotate +45 degrees, (Clockwise), it actually rotates the quad by -45 degrees (Anit-clockwise).

But hopefully, this will help anyone who has a similar problem in the future.