# Using Matrix. Rotate in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, translate-animation

**Edit** - Added more code

Having a lot of problems attempting to correctly rotate my quad using OpenGL ES 2.0.

It always seems to rotate around the centre of the screen co-ordinates.  I'm trying to get it to rotate around it's own centre (for 2d, so z axis only).

I've been experimenting with Matrix.translate as show below.  However, changing the x or y pos here simply draws the quad at a different place on the screen, but when it rotates, again it rotates around the centre of the screen.  Please could someone explain how to get it to spin around it's own z axis (like a wheel)?

Thanks, here are the relevant lines of code - if more is needed, please ask and I will post.  (Please note, I've looked at a lot of similar questions on SO and the wider internet but I've not managed to find an answer thus far).

Thanks.

```
//Set rotation
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

//Testing translation
Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -.5f, .5f, 0f);

// Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0);
```

**My Shaders (declared at class level)**

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

"attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
"void main() {" +
" gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
"}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
"precision mediump float;" +
"uniform vec4 vColor;" +
"void main() {" +
" gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
"}";
```

**From onSurfaceChanged**

```
float ratio = (float) width / height;
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

**In My onDrawFrame method**

```
// Set the camera position (View matrix)
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//Calculate the projection and view transformation
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

I´ve encountered the same problems (seen weird distortions and everything else), my solution based on the [Android Training > Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES > Adding Motion](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion.html) below.

(Head over to my detailed post for at if needed:
[OpenGL ES Android Matrix Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480043/opengl-es-android-matrix-transformations/17292894#17292894).)

1. Set a *mModelMatrix* to identity Matrix

   ```
   Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0); // initialize to identity matrix
   ```
2. Apply translation to the *mModelMatrix*

   ```
   Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -0.5f, 0, 0); // translation to the left
   ```
3. Apply rotation to a *mRotationMatrix* (angles in degrees)

   ```
   Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
   ```
4. Combine rotation and translation via *Matrix.multiplyMM*

   ```
   mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
   ```
5. Combine the model matrix with the projection and camera view

   ```
   mTempMatrix = mMVPMatrix.clone();
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
   ```

Comment: Differentiating the movement and rotation (and later multiplying two matrixes) did the trick. Just note that rotation matrix initialization is required.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a walkthrough.  Let's say you were to draw a teapot... the modelMatrix would be an identity to start with.  The shape is centered on the origin like this:

[image: pre rotate and translate]

Verify this is what you have before you continue...

Once you have you should apply the rotation to the model matrix, compile+run - you get a rotated copy...

[image: rotated]

Once you have this you can translate:

[image: rotated and translated]

So for you, all you need to do appears to verify when rotation matrix is identity e.g.
Matrix.setIdentityM( mRotationMatrix,0); 
that the shape is in the center.  If it is not move it to the center.

Once it is in the center apply the rotation e.g.

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM( mRotationMatrix,0); 
    <as needed movement to center>

    Matrix.rotate(mRotationMatrix, 0, -angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    <any other translation you want>
```

Do it in steps to make your life easy so you see what is going on.

Comment: Hi @paulczak - thank you for this.  the thing is, when the shape is in the center, it rotates perfectly (because it's center is in the center of the screen).  However, if I move the shape to say the top left corner, then it still rotate or 'orbits' around the center.  I'm not sure how to translate it so that it stays in the same place? So when you say 'once you have this you can translate' - I think that's where I'm falling down, I'm not sure how to do this translation? (Order of code and how to work out where the center should be).

Comment: Are you resetting the rotation matrix (where you are doing your model transformations) to identity on each call of onDrawFrame()?

Comment: Actually I didn't have a Matrix.setIdentityM( mRotationMatrix,0); line in there at all - but I've added it now just before I use setRotate.  Yes, it is called every frame. (From my rotateQuad() method which is called from my onDrawFrame() method), your help is appreciated, I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Strangley, if I apply the translation to the mRotationMatrix and pass that matrix directly to the shader (in my case declared as "uniform mat4 uRotate" and then edit my shader to "gl_Position = uRotate * a_position;\n"+ (thereby not using uMVPMatrix) it kind of seems to work.  I say kind of as I'm still getting the distortion I talk about in my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836688/correct-vertex-shader-code-opengl-es-2-0) and I'm not happy about not using uMVPMatrix as I know it should work with this.  Something must be wrong with my code!  Thanks again for any help.

Comment: You could pass in the Model/View/Project matrices into the shader and have it computed like this:  gl_Position = Model*View*Projection*mVertex;  But that string of multiplications is the same every time for a lot of vertices (10s of thousands for models with lots of vertices) so it's usually given to the shader as an MVP or as M and VP if you need to do phong lighting...  So that is a potential approach that will run slower - if you'll see it in the application you have is another question.

Comment: thanks.  I'm not sure I really understand what you said there.  However, I would ask this - with the source code over at https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html, (This draws a triangle which you can rotate with your finger).  How would you move that triangle and keep it's point of origin within it's centre?  This is the code I am basing my rotation on.... Again, I've tried with this example but I'm really found it impossible to accomplish.  If you could advise how this is done, I could probably adapt it to my code - thanks again!!

Comment: I'm going to re-ask this question as I still have the same problem - I will try to work it better.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation usually occurs around the origin, so you want to rotate your quad before you translate it. If you rotate after you translate, then the quad will first be moved away from the origin, then rotated around the origin.

Without knowing how your Matrix function are implemented, we cannot advise on whether you are using them correctly. All you've show us in the functions' interface.

But in general, rotate *before* you translate.

Comment: Hi @Sebby Johanns. Thanks for the comment,  Am I not rotating before translation at the moment?  Would be grateful if you could explain in more detail - I've added some more code - is this enough?  Please advise if you need any more (and which part you require) - thanks so much!!

Comment: If the translation is intended to move the center of rotation, and not to move the quad, then you translate, rotate, translate back.

Comment: @mbeckish thanks for the comment, I've heard people say 'traslate and translate back' but I've yet to understand it completely,  I think you mean to translate the x and y and then re-translate with the opposite values (say, 1,1 and then -1,-1) - please could you edit to show an example?  I have tried this but I get nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you want to translate the object so that it is centered on the origin.  If you drefined it drawn around 0,0 then it's good enough to start with the identity matrix, then rotate, then translate the rotated version to where you want it.  After that you can multiply together the model, view and projection matrices to get the uniform you'll send to the shader (unless you are lighting then send MV and P separately so you can correctly calculate your shading).

Comment: What exactly is translate supposed to do?  Move the centre/pivot point of the quad or move the quad itself?  And is this the best approach for what I need?  (Basically I'm writing a simple framework for 2d games so just want a method that will rotate sprites)

Comment: Thanks @paulczak, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the concept of rotation in OpenGL ES 2.0 - please could you show me an example of what you mean as nothing I'm trying seems to work. Thank you. Basically I trying to get my quad to rotate on the spot.

Comment: Translate means to move the center of your quad, yes. This is the same as moving the quad itself. It moves your quad so that its center is in a new place in 3D space. Most objects in graphics are moved around by a process of rotating them, followed by translating them. Of course, you can do this in the opposite order if you want rotation to also affect location, not just orientation. Now these `Matrix` functions you are using are not OpenGL specifically. I assume these are a library built into the OS you are using so I cannot comment on whether you are using them correctly.

Comment: They are part of the Android API for OpenGL ES 2.0 @SebbyJohanns

Answer (score 0):

Apply your operations backwards:

1st- Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -.5f, .5f, 0f);

2nd- Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

It will rotate around its own center